# Loosing focus when interacting with Unity UI on WEBGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, unity-webgl

When I run my app on webGl that was build by Unity I am loosing focus when I interact with UI element. I am having simple crosshair and when menu is not enabled then I locked cursor.

[image]

Here is a sample code

```
if(isCanvasMode)
    {
      Cursor.visible = true;
      Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    }
    else
    {
      Cursor.visible = false;
      Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }
```

At this stage all works perfectly fine, I do not see cursor and navigation works as expected.
When I open menu (isCanvasMode = true), all works as expected I can navigate on menu items with the cursor. The problem occurs when I close the menu and set isCanvasMode to false then I am loosing focus and when navigating in horizontal direction with mouse, cursor suddenly moved to another screen (it only works fine when I close the menu and then click again on the unity window).
I am using TextMeshPro Button if that makes any difference.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find solution just in case anyone is facing similar problem.
So previously when I clicked close button it called function that would set the cursor in to locked state :

```
Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked
```

Solution:
Create your custom Button that derived from Button class and override OnPointerDown method. The code will look like that.

```
public override void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
  {
    base.OnPointerDown(eventData);
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked
  }
```